# How do I display the data from the last to the first with a multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays

So I'm new to coding and I was looking at arrays and I want to know if it's possible to display the last piece of data from an array first and the first piece of data to be last. This is the code I have.

```
<?php

$trans = array
    (
        array("10/3/22",1,54),
        array("10/48/32", 54,54),
        array("3/29/2018", 54, 128.84)
    );

echo '<table border="1">';
echo '<tr><th>Date</th><th>Before Balance</th><th>After Balance</th></tr>';
foreach ($trans as $tran) {
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach( $tran as $data ) {
        echo '<td>' . $data . '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: you want array values flipped? you could use `array_reverse` in `$trans` if you want

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php There's any of a number of ways to do it.  Check out the docs first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `array_reverse` as follows in your forloop

```
foreach (array_reverse($trans) as $tran) {
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach( $tran as $data ) {
        echo '<td>' . $data . '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
array_reverse($array);
```

For more info http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php